# UIWebView scalesPageToFit = true does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I'm new to IOS Swift and need some help. I've followed other examples found in this forum but no luck. 
No matter what I do, the webpage won't scale to fit the UIwebview.

Please help.

Below is the code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.bbc.co.uk");        
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);        
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
        webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit        
        webView.delegate = self;       
        webView.frame = self.view.bounds    

    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.style.zoom= 5.0;")
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        let zoom = webView.bounds.size.width / webView.scrollView.contentSize.width
        webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: Did you try putting <code>webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;</code> in the delegate method <code>shouldStartLoadWithRequest</code>